# Issue with shared sorting function in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting

I have a list of users with properties and I want to output a best list according to each propertly. When I comment out `"nrGames": sorter(allUsersWithStats, "nrGames")` it correctly sorts according to elo, but if I don't, both are sorted according to nrGames. I guess somehow I need to use a new instance of `allUsersWithStats` to prevent it but I am not exactly sure.

```
async function getRankedUserList() {
    allUsersWithStats = await getAllUsersWithStats();
    topList = {
        "elo": sorter(allUsersWithStats, "elo"),
        "nrGames": sorter(allUsersWithStats, "nrGames"),
    }
    return topList;
}

function sorter(allUsersWithStats, propertyName) {
    return allUsersWithStats.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b[propertyName] - a[propertyName];
    });
}
```

The `allUsersWithStats` Array looks like this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    elo: 962,
    nrGames: 2,
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    elo: 979,
    nrGames: 3,
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function mutates the array.

So you should copy the array first and then send it to your function

```
async function getRankedUserList() {
    allUsersWithStats = await getAllUsersWithStats();
    topList = {
        "elo": sorter([...allUsersWithStats], "elo"),
        "nrGames": sorter([...allUsersWithStats], "nrGames"),
    }
    return topList;
}
```

Or

```
function sorter(allUsersWithStats, propertyName) {
    return [...allUsersWithStats].sort(function (a, b) {
        return b[propertyName] - a[propertyName];
    });
}
```